# Browse for File buttons save as hyperlink in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a form I have multiple attachment fields where I insert hyperlinks (right click edit hyperlink). 
All files are located on a networkdirectory

```
\\ap1\tools\db...
```

I would like to have a button with an on click event that opens a "browse for file" starting in

`\\ap1\tools\db...`

and that puts the selected file as hyperlink into the appropriate field.

I think vba is the best solution but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I believe I have solved my own question

```
 Private Sub btnAttachment1_Click()

   Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3

   Dim fd As Object
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
   With fd
'Set the initial path to the D:\Documents\ folder.
   .InitialFileName = "\\ap1\tools\db\"
   .Title = "Select Attachment"
'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
'If the user presses the action button...
   If .Show = -1 Then
'   DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
   Me![Attachment1] = "#" & .SelectedItems(1) & "#"

'  **

'If the user presses Cancel...
   Else
   End If
 End With

'Set the object variable to Nothing.
   Set fd = Nothing


End Sub
```